# 2nd data table don't show "no data available" message

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I have 2 data tables:
Table 1

```
<table id="properties_list" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="backend_tab_header">
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Photo</th>
        <th>Property ID</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Date Created</th>
        <th>Owner</th>  
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
    foreach ($properties as $property)
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php print $property["status"]; ?></td>
            <td class="pic_prop_table"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php print $property["url"]; ?>" ></td>
            <td><?php print $property["prop_id"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php print $property["address"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php print $property["date_created"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php print $property["first_name"]; ?>&nbsp;<?php print $property["last_name"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }

  ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Table 2

```
<table id="messages_list" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="backend_tab_header">
                        <th>Property ID</th>
                        <th>Subject</th>
                        <th>Message</th>
                        <th>Received</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                    foreach ($properties as $property)
                    {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php print $messages["from_user"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php print $messages["subject"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php print $messages["message"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php print $messages["date_sent"]; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }   
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

and to fill the arrays call my php functions on top of the page:

```
$properties = $auth_user->getPropertiesByUser($_SESSION['user_session']);   
$messages = $auth_user->getMessages($_SESSION['user_session']);
```

The data tables are create with JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
jQuery('table#properties_list').DataTable( {
    //ajax:           '../ajax/data/arrays.txt',
    scrollY:        200,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging:         false
} );
jQuery('table#messages_list').DataTable( {
    //ajax:           '../ajax/data/arrays.txt',
    scrollY:        200,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging:         false
} );
```

});

My problem is that when the first array($properties) return empty the first table show the message "No data available in table" and also when both arrays($properties and $messages) return empty both tables show the message "No data available in table", but when $properties array return with info and $messages array return empty the 2nd table(messages)don't show the "No data available in table" and also creates as much `<td>` elements as `<td>` elements in the firs table(properties). Can anyone tell me what could be the cause of this behaviour?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The second call it looks like you're referencing $properties instead of $messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably it's because both of the for each in pop use the $properties. On second loop, it gets the $prperties of the first.

Try to set $properties = array() before getting the values or use another variable name.